# Does AWS log that a message was moved to SQS DLQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a SQS queue and a Lambda which reads messages from the queue. I have a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) configured and working. I can see failed messages being delivered to the DLQ, its "Messages Available" in the AWS Console goes up.

When AWS moves the messages to the DLQ will this be logged in Cloud Watch?

By "logged", I mean an entry/row/event created in CloudWatch that:

- indicates that a message has been delivered to a DLQ
- ideally specifies:

  - DLQ name
  - some message/event unique id
  - lambda that was processing the message
- optionally specifies the message body/payload

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean? CloudWatch Logs to log entire body of the DLQ message, or CloudWatch metric for failed lambda execution?

Comment: I doubt that it is logged. The log entry is created by the Lambda function that is running (which is why the Lambda function requires `logs:` permission). However, moving a message to a Dead Letter Queue is done by the AWS Lambda **service**, which does _not_ send logs to CloudWatch Logs.

Comment: @Marcin I added some more details to the question, hope it helps. I guess I am after any log event that tells me a msg went to a DQL, having the message body is optional, I don't really need that.